# npm install becrypt failed Debien weezy

Tags: node.js, npm, debian, node-modules

i cant install becrypt on debian wheezy. i got error when trying to install using command "npm install becrypt".

error like this

> ```
>  npm install bcrypt
> ```

```
/
> bcrypt@0.8.5 install /home/abdulmanaf/test/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:78:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:82:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:93:16
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/abdulmanaf/test/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.8
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-0.bpo.4-amd64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "bcrypt"
npm ERR! node v0.12.8
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! bcrypt@0.8.5 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@0.8.5 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/abdulmanaf/test/node_modules/npm-debug.log
```

what is the actual issue related with this.?

Comment: `gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make`: install make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All You need to build `bcrypt` > 0.7.7 is:

```
apt-get install python make g++
```

**bcrypt dependencies**:

- NodeJS
- node-gyp
- Windows users will need the options for c# and c++ installed with their visual studio instance.
- Python 2.x
- OpenSSL - This is only required to build the bcrypt project if you are using versions <= 0.7.7. Otherwise, we're using the builtin node crypto bindings for seed data (which use the same OpenSSL code paths we were, but don't have the external dependency).

Answer (score 0):

If you read the error lines, you can find out that `make` is not found. To Install make you can run the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install make build-essential
```